# backup incremental vs diferencial no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup

Sempre que preciso configurar a rotina de backup de um banco de dados SQL Server eu confundo esses dois tipos de backup. Portanto eu gostaria de saber:

- O que cada um faz?
- Considerando que faço um backup full no domingo, quando eu tiver que restaurar um banco tenho que restaurar cada um dos arquivos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você disse que faz um backup full no domingo, vamos partir desse cenário.

Quando você fizer um backup incremental na terça, ele terá os dados que
foram alterados na segunda e você faz outra na quarta que terá os dados 
alterados na terça e assim sucessivamente.

Um backup diferencial na terça, por exemplo, não teria diferença do incremental,
mas um backup diferencial na sexta, teria todas as mudanças ocorridas na semana e seria igual a soma de todos os backups incremental.

Do mesmo modo, se você fizer um backup incremental na sexta não teria diferença de um backup diferential também feito na sexta.

Para restaurar teria dois caminhos. Restaure o backup full do domingo e todos os incrementais feitos durante a semana ou o full do domingo e o diferencial da sexta, claro, dependendo do método de backups que você escolheu.

Comment: pra facilitar a memorização: o DIFERENCIAL contém tudo que tem de DIFERENTE entre o banco atual e o backup full né?
minha rotina de backup está errada então, estou fazendo incrementais mas substituindo o arquivo, nunca vou conseguir restaurar completamente dese jeito.

Comment: Fazendo incremental você precisa guardar todos até o próximo backup full.